# Composting/Post processing animation

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, node-editor, compositing-nodes

Sorry if this is the wrong place (I tried researching).

**1.** Could someone explain difference between post-processing and compositing in terms of animation.

**2.** Is it possible to animate(key frame) compositing ex. A warm feel is added for first 5 seconds(sunset) then its night (so instead of a warm feel a more cold dark feel) so I need to change the compositing throughout the animation.

**3.** Should I instead just create the animation normally and composite it in another software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going through each part of the question, one by one:

1. Post-processing and compositing are **pretty much the same thing**. Post processing is generally more color oriented, and compositing is a bit more VFX oriented (keying etc. ). But for all intents and purposes in blender, they are the same thing, and done at the same time, in the same place.
2. Yes, you can **key frame** nearly every single **property value in the compositor**, the key is just to choose the right ones when working with colors, or odd things can happen...
3. Yes, you'll do the compositing/post-pro last, **You can do it all in blender**, or use different software, like Adobe After effects, or the now 'free'* [Fusion 7](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/fusion). For the color stuff (Post-Pro), you could use After Effects, Adobe Speed Grade, or [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve). Most of this software isn't cheap, which is why I recomend doing it in blender, which for the large part, has a fully capable feature set.

<sub>*Non commercial, with some non-key features removed, the full version costs about $1000</sub>

Comment: Using After Affects for my intro anyway might as well use it for composition, I had a feeling my it would be all this just wasn't sure thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: I'd use AE if you have it... I bought it even though I know and used the blender compositor for over a year. Way better in my mind!

Comment: Hmmm, its proving quite hard to find tutorials on how to composite or post process 3d animations in AE. Would you know any good sits? Also did you mean AE or blender that's way better in your mind.

Comment: AE is better, by far. As far as post processing 3d animations, you render them out as a png sequence (or any other file format, and treat them like camera footage). For composting, you may wan't a [depth map](http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/depth_compositing/)[Rendering a depth would be a separate question... just look it up], and maybe some object matts, but otherwise, treat it like regular footage